# Delete and Edit button onClick

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have two buttons Edit and Delete which displays a modal view that I call through ajax script. how do I tell ajax which function to execute if button edit/delete is clicked either way.

```js
var DisplayCedant = function(cedantid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LifeData/EditCedant",
    data: {
      CedantId: cedantid
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#myModalBodydiv").html(response);
      $("#myModalForm").modal("show");
    }
  })
}
var DisplayCedant = function(cedantid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LifeData/DeleteCedant",
    data: {
      CedantId: cedantid
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#myModalBodydiv").html(response);
      $("#myModalForm").modal("show");
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-button-action">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="DisplayCedant(@item.Id)" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-note" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="form-button-action">
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" onclick="DisplayCedant(@item.Id)"><i class="icon-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. If you want each button to do something different, create 2 separate functions and call the relevant one from each button. 2. Do not use `onclick` attributes. They are outdated and not good practice. Bind your event handlers unobtrusively using native JS (`addEventListener()`) or jQuery (`on()`)

Comment: You have 2 functions both called "display" - change one to `var editCedant = function...` and the other to `var deleteCedant = function...`

Comment: Got it, thank you for this inputs. By the way how do i pass my model value @item.id to the jquery using the on method in jquery?